# Display application icon in the title bar

Tags: unity, icons, titlebar

In Unity's default configuration the title bar looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to achieve this:
[image]

Is it possible to show the icon of the application in the title bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now it was a metacity related question. I added 

`<icon x="(width - title_width) / 2 - mini_icon_width - 7" y="(height - title_height) / 2 " width="mini_icon_width" height="mini_icon_height" />`
to the `<draw_ops>` respective tag in the metacity file theme and it did what I wanted.